# SS_HTTPRequest could not be converted to a string

Tags: php, forms, silverstripe

I have a SilverStripe (3.4) Page with a form that would work if I didn't have a `DataObject` in it.

```
public function AntwortForm($ID) {

    $Nummer = Vortest_Fragen::get()->byID($ID);
    if ($Nummer) {
        $Art=$Nummer->Art;
    }
    if ($Art == 'Normal') {
        $fields = new FieldList(
            TextAreaField::create('Antwort'),
            HiddenField::create('ID', 'ID', $ID),
            HiddenField::create('VortestID', 'VortestID', $this->request->param('ID')),
            HiddenField::create('Aktion', 'Aktion', $this->request->param('Action'))

        );
    } else {
        $Optionen = explode(';', $Nummer->Optionen);
        $a = 'A';

        for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count ($Optionen); $i++) {
            $Op[$a] ='<div style="width:25px;display:inline;">' . $a . ')</div> ' . $Optionen[$i];
            $a++;
        }

        $fields = new FieldList(
            CheckboxSetField::create('Antwort', 'Antwort', $Op),
            HiddenField::create('ID', 'ID', $ID),
            HiddenField::create('VortestID', 'VortestID', $this->request->param('ID')),
            HiddenField::create('Aktion', 'Aktion',$this->request->param('Action')),
            HiddenField::create('Art', 'Art', $Nummer->Art)
        );
    }
    $actions = new FieldList(
        FormAction::create('AntwortEintragen', 'Eintragen')
    );

    $form = new Form($this, 'AntwortForm', $fields, $actions);
    return $form;
}

function AntwortEintragen($data, $form) {
    $Antwort = Vortest_Antwort::get()->filter(array('FrageID' => $data['ID'], 'SchreiberID' => Member::currentUserID()));
    foreach($Antwort as $item) {
        $item->delete();
    }

    foreach ($data['Antwort'] as $Antwort) {
        $Ant .= $Antwort . ',';
    }
    $Antwort = new Vortest_Antwort();

    if ($data['Antwort']) {
        $form->saveInto($Antwort);
        if ($data['Art'] == 'Mechanics') {
            $Antwort->Antwort = $Ant;
        }
        $Antwort->SchreiberID = Member::currentUserID();
        $Antwort->FrageID = $data['ID'];
        $Antwort->write();
    }
    $VID = $data['VortestID'];
    if ($data['Aktion'] == 'AlleFragen') {
        $this->redirect('/vortest/AlleFragen/' . $VID . '#' . $data['FrageNr']);
    } elseif ($data['Aktion'] == 'Einzelfrage') {
        $this->redirect('/vortest/Einzelfrage/' . $VID);
    } else {
        $this->redirect('/vortest/Test/' . $VID.'#' . $data['FrageNr']);
    }
}
```

It works when I change the `$ID` to a number in this line `$Nummer = Vortest_Fragen::get()->byID($ID);`

When I don't change it I get the following error:

```
[Recoverable Error] Object of class SS_HTTPRequest could not be converted to string
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Could you re indent the code, makes it easier to non german people read the code and get the gist of the flow faster also id remove all unnecessary code from there also. Anyways the error is quite self explanatory: AntwortForm($ID)  < naming variable as $ID doesn't mean that its an ID if you var dump($id) its presumably SS_HTTPRequest type. Doesn't $this->request->param("ID") have the right value?

Comment: I've had a similar problem. Here's the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/37874804/4363418

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit form within controller extension - SilverStripe 3.4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874714/submit-form-within-controller-extension-silverstripe-3-4-0)

Answer (score 0):

Althought it is not clearly documented, Silverstripe secretly passes a request argument to and form methods on a controller. Your $ID argument is actually not what you think it is, you will find it is actually an SS_HTTPRequest object that Silverstripe has passed (without you realising).

**To fix this, change the first line:**

`public function AntwortForm($ID) {`

**To:**

`public function AntwortForm($request, $ID) {`

And make sure you update anywhere that you call this method :-)